# where OR where mysql - mysql query with two where clauses

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got an SQL statement:

```
$sql =" SELECT DISTINCT
            scr.*  
        FROM scr 
            LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.user_id=scr.user_id

        WHERE $email_filter LOWER(scr.genre) LIKE '%$search_word_fix%' **HERE** $psez protage $wwc $prevoption $locatio  $rats $rat1 $rat2 $rat3 $rat4          
        GROUP by scr.sp_name  
        ORDER BY scr.grade DESC";
```

when I add lower(scr.classification) like '%$search_word_fix%' in "HERE"
it doesn't display the correct results.
I was thinking something like (where scr.genre = "searchkeyword" and other filters here) OR (where scr.classification ="searchkeyword" and other filters here)

Comment: Yes, you need an `AND` or an `OR` between the conditions in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I don't know your script: But make sure to sanitize any user-input before passing it into a query.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string`! Use it!

Comment: **WARNING** your code is susceptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Also, why are you using `LOWER`? MySQL has a case insensitive collation by default. Did you change it? Did you change it intentionally?

Comment: @DanielA.White its not the code Im using I simplified it, I have functions to sanitize and secure it from sql injections thanks tho

Comment: @FritsvanCampen it works with lower returns results from both lower and capitalized characters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only specify Where once.  Additional clauses are specified just with "or" and "and"

Use parans to group order of operations

```
where (scr.genre = "searchkeyword" and other filters here) 
OR (scr.classification ="searchkeyword" and other filters here)
```